# ubuntu 13.04 moving mouse cursor with keyboard is very slow

Tags: ubuntu

( I cant get keynav to run on ubuntu 13)

I saw that in system -> keyboard -> you can set the keyboard to move the mouse cursor.

However, it moves very slow.  (not feasible at all)

Tried to speed up the mouse cursor speed, but that doesnt help.

has anyone figured out how to speed up the mouse cursor speed when it is being moved by keyboard in ubuntu 13

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution: reduce the delay of the repeating of the keys. Because if you click the arrow-key for example, then there is a delay between the repeating. So you have to do the repeating "faster".

1. Open `System Settings`
2. Click on `Keyboard`
3. Under `Repeat Keys` lower the slider `Delay`?
4. Under `Repeat keys` raise the `Speed` slider.

Now your movement should be faster.

Comment: doesnt work for mouse cursor speed increase.  however, typing is a blast at high speed.(ie it works for typing not for moving cursor)